# "Undefined method `build'" when using Rspec + FactoryBotRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying this gem called [FactoryBotRails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails). For some reason, when I try it on one of my models unit tests, the following error is thrown.

> Failure/Error: my_model = build(:my_model)
>         NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `build' for #\<\RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyModel::ValidationTests:0x000055c553959958>

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as long as I have followed several tutorials on the web, and did the same steps.

---

Added, in:

gemfile

```
gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 5.1.1'
```

app/spec/support/factory_bot.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

spec/factories/my_models.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_model do
    name { 'some name' }
    code { 'some code' }
  end
end
```

And used it like:

```
my_model = build(:my_model)
```

---

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: How about `FactoryBot.build(:my_model)`

Comment: Do you have `require 'rails_helper'` in your spec file?

Comment: @ThuyNguyen, I tried that too. But it didn't work =/.

Comment: @AkhayGoyal, Yes, I do :)

Comment: Can you show your whole block of codes, that contains `build(:my_model)` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might not be *what* you're calling, but *where* you're calling it. `my_model = build(:my_model)` is not syntax you want to use while writing specs, and the error message looks maybe you're calling it from outside of a spec? Because if you're calling it from within a spec, the error should be something along the lines of `ArgumentError: Factory not registered: my_model`. The spec itself should look like this:

```rb
# spec/models/my_model_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe MyModel do
  let(:my_model) { build :my_model }

  it { expect(my_model).to be_valid }
end
```

I would also specify the model name in your factory declaration (i.e., `factory :my_model, class: 'MyModel' do`). If you want to play with your factories, you can start up a test console:

```rb
# start rails console in 'test' environment
rails console test
my_model = FactoryBot.build :my_model
```

Note that you will need to use `FactoryBot.build` instead of `build` in your test console.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, please update your post with the contents of the spec you're trying to run, how you're trying to run it, and expand your definition of your `spec/rails_helper.rb` file. Since you're new to RSpec, I also suggest checking out http://www.betterspecs.org/ for best practices.

Comment: I've having an identical issue as the OP, and this did not help

Comment: @Jessa ...then I encourage you to write your own question explaining your own setup/configuration and error messages? I answered based on what kind of scenario could result in that error message and requested that the OP provide additional missing details if their issue wasn't resolved. The OP hasn't said anything or provided the necessary additional missing details and you haven't provided any details about your setup either, so I'm not sure what you're seeking to accomplish here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Allison. And sorry for the late reply. As soon as I can, I will try what you mentioned ^^

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing to setup shortcuts for FactoryGirl by including its methods in your `rails_helper`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```